# Modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Please explain why `self` is used in `def self.included (klass)` below.

```
module A
  def self.included(klass)
    puts "A -> #{klass}"
    puts A
    puts self
  end
end

class X
  include A
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By writing `def self.included` you are defining a method that is part of the singleton class of module A.  In general, singleton methods can only be called by doing `A.included()` but this singleton method has a special name `included` that causes the Ruby interpreter to call when the module gets included in to a class.

A normal method in a module (defined with `def foo`) can only be called if the module gets included in to something else.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you declare a module method that can be called directly. Normally methods defined within a module are only usable if another class or module includes them, like class X in this example.

```
module Example
  def self.can_be_called
    true
  end

  def must_be_included
    true
  end
end
```

In this case you will see these results:

```
Example.can_be_called
# => true

Example.must_be_included
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `must_be_included' for Example:Module
```

The `self` declared methods are not merged in to the classes or modules that include it, though. They are special-purpose that way.